# eppy - scripting language for E+, Energyplus

Tags: python, energyplus

I tried to launch first commands of eppy package but I received strange errors:

```
from eppy import modeleditor

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    from eppy import modeleditor
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\eppy\modeleditor.py", line 26, in <module>
    from eppy.idfreader import idfreader1
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\eppy\idfreader.py", line 24, in <module>
    from eppy.idf_msequence import Idf_MSequence
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\eppy\idf_msequence.py", line 27, in <module>
    class Idf_MSequence(collections.MutableSequence):
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableSequence'
```

I noticed that maybe there are some missing files but I'm not sure. I compared my files with GitHub folder:

**Screeshot:**

[image: Screenshot]

The folder resources is missing...
I don't know if this is the problem.
I installed eppy package simply with the command: `pip install eppy`
Can you help me?
Thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I found the issue.
The problem appears only with Python 3.10, with Python 3.9 disappears.
I don't know why...

Regarding the folder "resources" you have to download it from GitHub, because the installation with pip doesn't download it.